# Django model using hashmap

Tags: django, django-models

I have a question about how to properly model my data in Django (and later in graphene).
I have a model `exam` which consists of `date, subject, participants, results` where `subject,participants, results` are references to other objects. I could of course have two lists of  `participants` and `results` however it would be practical to have a map of type:

pseudocode:

`results= map(participant,result)`

To be honest I do not know if this is even possible without introducing a additional model object `participant_results`

Any insight very welcome.

Benedict

Comment: Can you not add this as a `@property` method on the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would model it this way:

```
class Exam(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    subject = models.TextField()
    
class Participant(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="participants")
    result = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    exam = models.ForeignKey(Exam, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = ...
```

You retrieve all participant from an exam using

```
exam.participants
```